# How can I write advanced calculator in Delphi without limitations of floating point types?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Hello I can calculate `17^1000` in calculator of windows 7 and it looks like

`1.2121254521552524e+123` (which seems to me to be not correct)

how can I write it in delphi and I want to use for example `1.2121254521552524e+123 mod 18`
or `1.2121254521552524e+123 mod 100`.

Another example: `17 mod 5 = 2`

How can I write it can anyone help me?

Comment: `17 over 1000` -> `17 / 1000` ->  `0.017`.

Comment: my english is bad. I m using google translate. 17^1000 :)

Comment: I get 2.81139.....e+1230 in Win7 calculator. Either way, the rest of your question with the 'mod' stuff is unclear.

Comment: I get the same result as Marc B on WinXP calculator (for 17^1000) (and agree about clarity)

Comment: OK :) How can I write the same windows's calculator?

Comment: So you are looking to re-create the Windows Calculator using Delphi-7?

Comment: no no no. I want to calculate 17^10000 and get to (17^10000) mod 21

Comment: so you want just those two results?

Comment: yes. I want to multiply huge number and show it 1.65435443543e+21 format and just get mod,mines,plus any number with it.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? because is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use some sort of extended precision type.  Such a type would not be a primitive type, you would need to either use an existing one or write your own (which would be a huge amount of work, and a classic case of reinventing the wheel).  Java might be a better language for this because its system libraries include BigInteger and BigDecimal classes, which handle the functionality you would need.

Edit: Here are some delphi libraries providing large integer and high precision floating point arithmetic: http://www.delphiforfun.org/programs/Library/big_integers.htm

That said, if you find yourself unable to use the windows calculator to accomplish what you are looking for and you only need this for one or two things, consider using a more powerful online service such as WolframAlpha.

Also, in case you still don't have an answer:

```
17^1000 mod 18  == 1
17^1000 mod 100 == 1
```

The algorithm used to compute numbers like these is simple and does not require large integer support.  Consider the following pseudocode:

```
modular_exponentiation (base, exponent, modulus):
    let value = 1
    let c_exponent = 0
    for c_exponent less than exponent:
        let value = value * base
        if value greater than or equal to modulus:
            let value = (value) mod (modulus)
        increment c_exponent
    value.
```

Comment: ı m new in programming. I m en mech. eng. in real life and delphi is a hobby for me. thank you for your answer but ı need an source code :)I want to get a program the same windows calculator.

Comment: That site has a link to both the compiled libraries and the source code at the bottom.  It also has a dependancy on some other libraries provided on the site, also available as either libraries or source, from the "library" link.

Comment: I use it but I couldnt write number in "e" format. I just want to write huge number in "e" format for example 17^100000 (1.55545554565556344e+101). then I want to do some calculation on the result.

Comment: 17^100000 is significantly bigger than that number.  Maybe your calculator really is broken.  When reading messages from your user interface, you can specifically process exponents of that format before doing other calculations.  17^100000 ~= 7.8e123044.  You could search specifically for the presence of "e" in a number and split it into the format `[number_1]e[number_2]` subject to the following rules: 1) whitespace surrounding the 'e' will be ignored; 2) number_1 may be omitted and if so shall have a value of 1; 3) number_2 may or may not have a unary '+' or '-' prefix, with '+' the default.

Comment: You can accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark.  Welcome to stackoverflow, enjoy your stay :)

Comment: +1 Make your life easy when evaluating 17^1000 mod 100 by never calculating 17^1000